# Ошибка в классе. php

Tags: php, классы

Изучаю классы. В общем, есть некий класс, а в нем два метода:

```
class loginAuth{

// Приватная функция фильтрации данных
function filtering($string){

    if ( is_array($string)){
        foreach ($string as $Skey => $Svalue) {         
            $f_array[$Skey] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($Svalue))));
        }

        return $f_array;
    } else {
        return htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($string))));
    }
}

// Смотрим, что нужно пользователю
function lookingForAction(){

    if ( !empty( $_POST['do'])) {
        $doWhat = $this->filtering($_POST['do']);
    } else {
        $doWhat = !empty( $_GET['do']) ? $this->filtering($_GET['do']) : "0";
    }

    switch ($doWhat) {
        case 'registration':
                return "registration";
            break;
        case 'restoration':
                return "restoration";
            break;
        case 'confirmation':
                return "confirmation";
            break;
        default:
                return "login";
            break;
    }
}
}
```

В методе `lookingForAction()`, который смотрит глобальные переменные `_GET` и `_POST`, для выбора действия нужно отфильтровать, но когда программа скрипт отрабатывает, ту часть, в которой требуется метод `filtering($string)`, выдает ошибку.

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in
> object context in
> Z:\home\test1.ru\www\class\login.class.php
> on line 40

Как я понял, что-то не так в синтаксисе, а понять, что не так, не могу.

Comment: @max3000, у вас функция lookingForAction лежит вне класса, но внутри организована, как метод (обращение к $this). Надо либо сделать ее методом класса, либо в ней создавать объект.

Comment: Неправильно код вставил. Обновил.

Comment: @max3000, покажите, как вызывается код. Там не должно быть этой ошибки, это серьезный баг, если это так.

Comment: В самом шаблоне, где указывается, что выдавать пользователю вход - регистрацию или востановление - в switch'e указана вот такая конструкция: `loginAuth::lookingForAction()`.

Comment: Сам класс http://s009.radikal.ru/i309/1412/5d/c4b15ad1da71.png  и шаблон http://i016.radikal.ru/1412/6e/03b0d2487b55.png больше php кода вообще нету, кроме этих файлов запрашиваемых в индекс файле.

Comment: @max3000, зачем вы нестатичный метод пытаетесь вызвать, как статичный?

Comment: Исправил, спасибо! Ошибка изчезла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in
> object context in
> Z:\home\test1.ru\www\class\login.class.php
> on line 40
>
> указана вот такая конструкция
> loginAuth::lookingForAction()

Вы пытаетесь вызвать публичный метод как статичный. В классе метод lookingForAction объявлен без модификатора, поэтому по умолчанию будет являться public-методом. Для данного типа методов требуется создание экземпляра объекта. В таком случае и будет доступен объект $this внутри методов класса.

```
$obAuth = new loginAuth();
$obAuth->lookingForAction();
```

[PHP:Область видимости](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php)